# Yii2 max filesize

Tags: php, yii, yii2

**My php.ini:**

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

**My model:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'name', 'description', 'image'], 'required'],
        [['user_id', 'is_active'], 'integer'],
        [['date_of_creation'], 'safe'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
        [['description'], 'string', 'max' => 512],
        [['players', 'level', 'time', 'best_time', 'fear', 'stress', 'teamwork', 'fun'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
        ['image', 'image', 'extensions' => 'jpg, gif, png, jpeg', 'maxSize' => 1024*1024*10, 'minWidth' => 100, 'minHeight' => 100],
    ];
}
```

**My error:**

```
Array ( [image] => Array ( [0] => The file "original_girl.jpg" is too big. Its size cannot exceed 2,097,152 bytes. ) )
```

Can enybody say what's wrong? In php.ini and in my model's rules I use **10 MB**.

Comment: upload_max_filesize in php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `post_max_size` directive in **php.ini** to send bigger files

```
post_max_size = 10M
```

And restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

Did you set Post Max Size too?

```
post_max_size=10M
```

You also need to set post_max_size in php.ini

Comment: @BohdanVorona see the phpinfo() and check post_max_size & upload_max_filesize variable, if that are showing greater size than the file size you are trying to upload. It must work.

Comment: @BohdanVorona what web server you are using? I'm assuming that you have already changed the configuration for max upload are per whatever server you are using. In case of nginx client_max_body_size is the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you use this one.....

```
[
     ['image'], 
     'file', 
     'extensions' => 'jpg, gif, png, jpeg', 
     'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false, 
     'maxSize' => 1024*1024*10
],
```

And change your .ini file